# how to add extra sapling presets

Tags: add-on

I have activated sapling addon. I have seen just 4 presets. I have found more presets [here](https://developer.blender.org/rBAc3a6d9132a44afd254fa120157c66e72b751e6f1)

I have found this addon [here](https://github.com/abpy/improved-sapling-tree-generator)

After installing i cant find the addon to activate.

[image]

Here are few more presets how can i add them. Do i have added separately or once there is no load button to add them. How can i add all those presets in sapling addon. Any suggestion or Help Thanks

Comment: The addon is shipped by defaul as part of blender  installation, no need to download and install it again. Those presets should be there already too, if not just paste the python files in the same directory as the existing ones.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I did not get u mean. Is that just copy all the .py files and paste in the sapling addon folder

Comment: Yes,search inside the addon folder where the presets are saved and paste the new ones there too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if relevant anymore but custom sapling addons are saved on

C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\presets\operator\add_curve_sapling

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the windows location for user  presets. (not linux or mac)  Will also look into  the scripts/presets folder of your installation.